# Unable to append shell variables to curl command

Tags: bash, shell, variables, curl

I am trying to store password in a shell variable. Once this step is done, I need to use this password in a curl command.

```
logmetPassword=$(echo "XXXXXXXXXXXXX==" | openssl enc -base64 -d | openssl enc -des3 -k mysalt -d)
curl -k -XPOST -d 'user=user@bg.vnetcom&passwd=$logmetPassword&space=myspace&organization=muOrg' https://mywebsite/login
```

The problem is, it takes `$logmetPassword` as it is witout substituting the value.
I've tried many options:

```
curl -k -XPOST -d 'user=user@bg.vnetcom&passwd=${logmetPassword}&  space=myspace&organization=muOrg' https://mywebsite/login
curl -k -XPOST -d 'user=user@bg.vnetcom&passwd="{$logmetPassword}"&space=myspace&organization=muOrg' https://mywebsite/login
curl -k -XPOST -d 'user=user@bg.vnetcom&passwd=\"{$logmetPassword}\"&space=myspace&organization=muOrg' https://mywebsite/log
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `$logmetPassword` substituted, you must enclose the argument (or that bit of the argument) in double quotes.  The shell does not expand any metacharacters inside single quotes.

You could use either of these:

```
curl -k -XPOST -d "user=user@bg.vnetcom&passwd=${logmetPassword}&space=myspace&organization=muOrg" https://mywebsite/login
curl -k -XPOST -d 'user=user@bg.vnetcom&passwd='"{$logmetPassword}"'&space=myspace&organization=muOrg' https://mywebsite/login
```

The first encloses everything in double quotes; the second only encloses the password in double quotes.  On the whole, I'd probably use the second, but the first is safe for the strings shown.